# xdvipdfmx warning when using Roboto font

Tags: fonts, xetex, xdvipdfmx

When using Roboto font with XeLaTeX, I meet the following warning:

```
xdvipdfmx:warning: Removed 14 null character(s) from fontname --> Roboto-Regular
```

The MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

I use `xelatex -no-pdf test` and `xdvipdfmx test` (assume the file name is `test.tex`) to compile. The version of Roboto font is `2.001101; 2014`.

Although I don't find anything incorrect in the PDF, but could anyone explain why there is such warning and how to suppress it?

Comment: I get the same warning. But why do you do it in two steps? The man page for `xdvipdfmx` says `It is used as the back end for xetex(1) and is not intended to be invoked directly.`

Comment: I can get more verbose output when invoking xdvipdfmx directly (with `-v`/`-vv` option).

Comment: I think this is a half answer to your question: In the one of the XeTeX source files (`source/texk/web2c/xetexdir/XeTeX_ext.c`) you find: `const char *outputdriver = "xdvipdfmx -q -E"; /* default to portable xdvipdfmx driver */`, which sets the default command to run the output driver. The `-q` option makes `xdvipdfmx` run silently, so that's why you don't see the warning when you let `xetex` run that for you. (Also, it shows you can use `xelatex -output-driver='xdvipdfmx -vv -E' test.tex` to accomplish your goal :)